# problem with Image in custom Cell

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiimage

Getting image data from sqlite database but not able to display in custom cell of imageview.is there any conversion of image data into image.

Comment: Show the code where you're grabbing said image from sqlite and code where you're trying to add it to the custom cell?

Answer (score 0):

Super easy. There's a UIImage convenience method for exactly that.

```
//assuming the existence of an NSData *myData
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:myData];
```

So easy, in fact, I suspect that's not actually your question. If not, please clarify what you're asking.